# merge two image using opencv 2.4.2 on android

Tags: android, image, opencv

I'am actually developing an application on Android and I'am using the libraries of OpenCV 2.4.2. I'am trying to merge two images in a single one:
In fact, I have two images of the same size but under different illumination value (One is brighter than the other) I'am trying to do a transformation of this two images in a way that : 
for exemple: 0.4*image1 + 0.6*image2 wich will give a combination of the two images in a single one(wich will have approximately a medium illumination value in this case ). 
How Can I do this using openCV 2.4.2 on android? 
I 'am actually getting A MAT matrix from the two images : Mat image1 = Highgui.imread(imgFile1.getAbsolutePath());
Mat image2 = Highgui.imread(imgFile2.getAbsolutePath());

The problem here is that I can not multiply the MAT matrix by a scalar value in a way that let me do such an operation(image3= a*image1 +b*image2 ) and after converting it(image3) into a bitmap and show it !
Is there another method to do that? Or do someone have a solution to that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`addWeighted`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#addWeighted%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29) function.